# Retrieve the particular entity from the request through a web request sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter, I want to retrieve from the request sample (it is on `websocket-request-response-sampler`).

The request body:

```
ws://localhost:8080/connect

{
    "uid": "JBM1",
    "agent_name": "performance_test_1"
}
```

I want to retrieve the agent name. Tried with normal JSSR223 post processer, not working. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done anything extra then @Dmitri rather few modifications, but please try it.

```
def requestBody = sampler.getPropertyAsString('requestData');
def jsonFormat = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(requestBody)

def key = 'agent_name'
def agentName= jsonFormat."$key"

log.info("AgentName"+ agentName)
vars.put('AgentNameFurther',agentName)
```

Comment: Thank you a ton, this really work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tried with "normal" [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) you're supposed to share your "normal" code you used and the "normal" [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file contents

I believe "normal" code should normally look like:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getPropertyAsString('requestData'))[0].get('agent_name')
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting   2022-01-30 20:49:24,774 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Text must not be null or empty
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]

Comment: I have declared like this String agentName = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getPropertyAsString('requestData'))[0].get('agent_name')

Comment: The answer relies to initial version of your question where the request data had `[]`, I'm not opening the question every 5 minutes to see whether you edited something or not. Just remove `[0]` from the code and it should start working (unless you change your request data again)